# Fantasy book about a guy who is slowly turning into stone after entering a different world through a mirror

Tags: story-identification, books

I’m dying to find this one book I read in like 2011 or something. I barely remember much but I think it was a guy who went through a mirror in an abandoned house or something? And he enters a different world. I think he gets sick or something or isn’t accustomed to the world and he’s slowly turning into stone? Onyx or something. And there’s a girl too I think who helps him find someone to cure him so he doesn’t turn into one of the people from that world. There’s also Smaragd people or something.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. If anyone correctly identifies the book you're looking for, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: It reminds me of "Mirrorworld" by Cornelia Funke. The mirror wasn't in an abandoned house though, and the boy turns into jade rather than onyx.

Comment: Was the book new at the time? I ask because "Mirror of Her Dreams", published in the 1980s, which might match (depending on how accurate the description above is).

Comment: A *smaragd* is an emerald, so is it possible the guy was turning to emerald rather than onyx?

Comment: The first book in Cornelia Funke's *Reckless* series, *The Petrified Flesh*, does match the description to some extent, thought the stone race are the *Goyl* and there is no mention of *Smaragd* in the book. The *Goyl* have a rock skin that can vary in colour and there is a subset of the *Goyl* who have onyx skin. Some of the Goyl have emerald green skin and it's possible the German edition describes this as *smaragd*. I have the English edition so I can't confirm this. Does any of this ring a bell?

Comment: My thought too @JohnRennie

Comment: I managed to find a copy of the German book and it only uses *smaragd* once when it refers to a green velvet gown as *smaragdfarbenem*. So this looks like a red herring.